# Kendo UI datepicker to capture by week

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I need to capture weeks instead a dates using Kendo UI datepicker. I need some like this (plz see the picture):

[image: Week picker]

Someone can give me the solution? I need to get the week number after select the week. any help? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

set the weekNumber to true.

```
   $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
       weekNumber: true,
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available in KendoUI at the moment.

It's been requested on the community forums and it looks like its still pending.

http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2952881-add-the-ability-to-display-a-week-number-column-to

> Add the ability to display a week number column to the Calendar & DatePicker controls and permit custom calculation of week number.